# how do i use a checkbox to change an animation play state

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox

How do i use a checkbox to change/toggle an animation play state from play to pause ( do i have to use js), I know it needs a bit more work but i am kind of stuck at this point as I know little to no javascript. ( any help would be greatly appreciated :) ) this is what I have so far:

```
<body id="body" onLoad="reset(); return true;">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="cloud">
        <div id="cloud1">
            <header id="topheader">

                <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" name="toggle"/>
                <label for="toggle"></label> 
             </header>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 </body>
#cloud{
background-image: url("../image/clouds.png");
background-size: 200% 200%;
background-position: -50% -50%;
-webkit-animation: cloud 120s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
-moz-animation: cloud 120s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
-o-animation: cloud 120s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
animation: cloud 120s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud {
0%{
  background-size: 200% 200%;
background-position: -50% -50%;  
}
50%{
 background-size: 150% 150%;
background-position: 0% 0%;   
}
100%{
 background-size: 100% 100%;
background-position: 50% 50%;   
}
}

@-moz-keyframes cloud {
0%{
  background-size: 200% 200%;
background-position: -50% -50%;  
}
50%{
 background-size: 150% 150%;
background-position: 0% 0%;   
}
100%{
 background-size: 100% 100%;
background-position: 50% 50%;   
}
}

@keyframes cloud {
0%{
  background-size: 200% 200%;
background-position: -50% -50%;  
}
50%{
 background-size: 150% 150%;
background-position: 0% 0%;   
}
100%{
 background-size: 100% 100%;
background-position: 50% 50%;   
}
}
@-o-keyframes cloud {
0%{
  background-size: 200% 200%;
background-position: -50% -50%;  
}
50%{
 background-size: 150% 150%;
background-position: 0% 0%;   
}
100%{
 background-size: 100% 100%;
background-position: 50% 50%;   
}
}

#cloud1{
background-image: url("../image/clouds1.png");
background-size: 200% 200%;
background-position: 150% 150%;
-webkit-animation: cloud1 150s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
-moz-animation: cloud1 150s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
-o-animation: cloud1 150s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
animation: cloud1 150s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud1 {
0%{
  background-size: 200% 200%;
background-position: 150% 150%;  
opacity: .8;
}
50%{
 background-size: 150% 150%;
background-position: 0% 0%; 
opacity: .5;
}
100%{
 background-size: 100% 100%;
background-position: -50% -50%; 
opacity: .3;
}
}

@-moz-keyframes cloud1 {
0%{
  background-size: 200% 200%;
background-position: 150% 150%;  
opacity: .8;
}
50%{
 background-size: 150% 150%;
background-position: 0% 0%; 
opacity: .5;
}
100%{
 background-size: 100% 100%;
background-position: -50% -50%; 
opacity: .3;
}
}

@keyframes cloud1 {
0%{
  background-size: 200% 200%;
background-position: 150% 150%;  
opacity: .8;
}
50%{
 background-size: 150% 150%;
background-position: 0% 0%; 
opacity: .5;
}
100%{
 background-size: 100% 100%;
background-position: -50% -50%; 
opacity: .3;
}
}
@-o-keyframes cloud1 {
0%{
  background-size: 200% 200%;
background-position: 150% 150%;  
opacity: .8;
}
50%{
 background-size: 150% 150%;
background-position: 0% 0%; 
opacity: .5;
}
100%{
 background-size: 100% 100%;
background-position: -50% -50%; 
opacity: .3;
}
}
input[type="checkbox"] { 
display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before{

content: "";
position: relative;
float: right;
margin: 1px;
padding: 2px;
background-image: url("../icons/pauseButton.png"); 
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;  
height: 27px;
width: 27px;
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
background-color: rgba(110, 0, 250, .5);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before{
content: "";
position: relative;
float: right;
margin: 1px;
padding: 2px;
background-image: url("../icons/playButton.png"); 
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;  
height: 27px;
width: 27px;
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
background-color: rgba(110, 0, 250, .5);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**animation-play-state**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state), then use jQuery to toggle a class on the element you are animating, where this is set to `paused`

> The animation-play-state CSS property determines whether an animation
>   is running or paused. You can query this property's value to determine
>   whether or not the animation is currently running; in addition, you
>   can set its value to pause and resume playback of an animation.
>
> Resuming a paused animation will start the animation from where it
>   left off at the time it was paused, rather than starting over from the
>   beginning of the animation sequence.

E.g, the class could simply be:

```
.paused{
   animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

The alternative would be to set the CSS property directly.

The simplest way to then alter with Javascript depending on checkbox state would likely to be to leverage jQuery (I appreciate you havent mentioned it) to do, e.g.:

```
    $('#toggle').click(function(e) {
        $('#cloud').toggleClass('paused', $('#toggle').is(':checked'));
    });
```

Comment: sorry I am still new to all this and I'm having a little trouble following. i have put this script in the head and this (.paused) class in the css, the checkbox still won't change the animation play state, do i need to set the #cloud and #cloud1 rules to play state running also? I really do appreciate the help :)

Comment: do I need to create any css rule for the #toggle id?